# Why do only the mounts of Shiva and Vishnu have actual names (Nandi and Garuda)?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, gods, durga

Do the VAhanas of Durga (lion), Ganesha (mouse), and Skanda (peacock) have names of their own, just like Shiva's mount is named "Nandi"?

Comment: Durga: Somanandi, Yama: Paundraka, Indra: Airavata, Kartikeya is either Indranila or Parvan can’t place it, Ganesha was from Mushakasura so he doesn’t have a name unless he retains his former name of Krauncha Gandharva. Also question title is opinion based but body is not and title and body don’t match with each other.

Comment: @Archit where did you get Somanandi and Indranila?

Comment: @Surya had read it in some purana (can’t place it) that this tiger used to accompany Devi Parvati during her tapasya to realise herself as the supreme mother (and arddhangini of Shiva). Afterwards he was blessed to be her vahana. His name was Somanandin. Indranila is based on some random reading don’t remember where so you can discount that one